# how to use time api in C under VS 2010 for windows

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

i am using `srand` function to generate random values as below on MS VS 2010.

```
srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );
```

i have been thrown with following error.

```
error C3861: 'time': identifier not found
```

Am i missing any thing here? can any one point out error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add `#include <ctime>` to the top of your program text (and be nice and say `std::time` while you're at it).

Answer (score 0):

You need to Include <**[ctime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/)**>

Answer (score 0):

include `time.h` (for time), `stdlib.h` (for srand) and Use `::` to access global scope.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f()
{
  ::srand( (unsigned)::time( NULL ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding  `#include <time.h>` should fix the problem if using C.